# Is a function of a centrality measure a centrality measure?

Tags: graph-theory, network-theory, complex-networks

I have been trying to wrap my head around the following question. Suppose you a have a centrality measure for a weighted, undirected network. Let's call the calculated centralities with $\pmb{x}>0$. Is a monotonic increasing function (just by simply studying the sign of the first derivative wrt. to $\pmb{x}$) of $\pmb{x}$ a centrality measure itself? My first guess was that since the orderings are preserved, it should be ok. The I started qondering if one could prove that this a centrality measure itself. Any tips/refs. are more than welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have in mind a precise definition of what is a "centrality measure"?

Comment: What i have in mind is just a qualitative version, which is a function that assign rankings to nodes